# json4s jackson - How to ignore field using annotations

Tags: json, scala, jackson, json4s

I`m using json4s-jackson(version 3.2.11).

I'm trying to ignore field using annotations(like jackson java version).

Here's exmaple:

```
case class User(id: Long, name: String, accessToken: String)
```

Following code is not working.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(Array("accessToken"))
case class User(id: Long, name: String, @JsonProperty("accessToken") accessToken: String)
```

Comment: BEWARE: Json4s is [vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial)!

Answer (score 9):

In json4s you can provide an instance of a field serialiser which can be configured to ignore or rename fields. Check the docs for more detail, but something like the following should work:

```scala
case class User(id: Long, name: String, accessToken: String)

val userSerializer = FieldSerializer[User](
  FieldSerializer.ignore("accessToken")
)

implicit val formats = DefaultFormats + userSerializer
```

Comment: how to make it work for multiple fields to be ignored?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a utility method, with Keys to remove as default parameter like this,

```
def removeKeys(entity:AnyRef, keys: List[String]=List("accessToken", "key1", "key2")): String= {
compact(Extraction.decompose(entity).removeField { x => keys.contains(x._1)})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending Steven Bakhtari's answer: if you want to ignore multiple fields you can do this:

```
FieldSerializer.ignore("config") orElse ignore("category")
```

as explained in this https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues/90 issue